# SSh permissions for aws EC2 instance Windows

Tags: windows, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssh, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am following [the guide])(https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/WSL.html) to link to my ec2 instance but I am having trouble copying my permissions.

[Look At this image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WoCwC.png)

When I run

```
cp C:/Users/Chase Austin/Desktop/Chase.pem ~C:/Windows/System32/wsl.exe
```

I get the error

```
cp: target '~C:/Windows/System32/wsl.exe' is not a directory
```

My .pem file is on my Desktop. how do i fix this

Edit 1

```
root@Chase:/mnt/c/Windows/System32# cp C:/Users/Chase Austin/Desktop/Chase.pem ~C:/Windows/System32/wsl.exe
cp: target '~C:/Windows/System32/wsl.exe' is not a directory


root@Chase:/mnt/c/Windows/System32# cp C:/Users/Chase Austin/Desktop/Chase.pem ~C:\Windows\System32\wsl.exe
cp: target '~C:WindowsSystem32wsl.exe' is not a directory
```

Edit 2

```
root@Chase:/mnt/c/Windows/System32# cp C:/Users/Chase Austin/Desktop/Chase.pem ~/Windows/System32/wsl.exe
cp: target '/root/Windows/System32/wsl.exe' is not a directory
```

Comment: What is `~C:` supposed to represent? `~` is a UNIX convention, not a Windows one. It's short for "my home directory".

Comment: I edited the question to have the exact screenshot of the part where I am having trouble. I just copied my wsl directory from my file explorer and pasted it in. Check out the picture i included

Comment: What I mean is ~C:\ is not valid notation. It's either `~/...` or `C:\...`.

Comment: Check my Edit 1

Comment: Again, to make it more clear: ~C:\ makes no sense. That's your problem. It's either ~/ or C:\ **NOT BOTH**. ~C: is *not* a directory. It's not lying!

Comment: I appreciate your help but I still don't fully understand. When i use ~/ I am still getting an error. Should I be calling the wsl.exe file?

Comment: As far as I know, `~` means nothing to Windows. Pay careful attention to the context in which those examples are given. UNIX uses different conventions. You may need to find Windows-specific examples.

Answer (score 0):

You have two problems here:

1) The file path has a space which means you need to put quotes around the file name: "C:/Users/Chase Austin/Desktop/Chase.pem".

2) You are trying to copy Chase.pem to the file wsl.exe. wsl.exe is a program and not a directory. wsl.exe is a Windows program that runs Linux program from the Windows Command Prompt.

I am assuming that your goal is to SSH to your AWS EC2 Instance. Just run ssh directly from Windows (ssh is included with the latest Windows 10 builds).

If your goal is to run ssh from the Linux subsystem, copy the file (as per the documentation) to your Linux instance - or the reverse, from the Linux instance copy the Windows file to Linux. Then run ssh from the Linux window.